# How do I create RSS feeds for a particular content type?

Tags: 8, feeds

I have created a custom *content entity type* form with 2 form fields:

- entity name (textfields)
- content type (drop-down list)

When I choose the content type from the entity form, and click on *Save*, an RSS feed of that selected content type should get generated.

How can I achieve this without using the Views module?

Is there any class that can be extended to generate RSS feeds?

Comment: @Kiamlaluno The edits which you have made in my question will put it in "Duplicate" mode. I specially highlight things like without using views module. I think, you shouldn't  edit question to this extent, it won't be re pliable now.

Comment: Please don't highlight questions. No, your question is not in any _duplicate_ mode. We don't use tags in titles.

Comment: http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/838/are-tags-allowed-in-questions-titles

Comment: lol, ok i got it